# Scala using toSet.toList vs distinct

Tags: list, scala, collections, set, distinct

If I want to get the unique elements of in a List I can either do a `distinct` or call `toSet.toList`. Which is more efficient and why ? Is there any other efficient way of doing this ? My understanding is that `distinct` will also maintain the order whereas `toSet.toList` won't.

```
scala> val mylist = List(1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,6,7)
mylist: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7)

scala> mylist.distinct
res11: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

scala> mylist.toSet.toList
res12: List[Int] = List(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken directly from the source code found [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L1):

```
/** Builds a new $coll from this $coll without any duplicate elements.
* $willNotTerminateInf
*
* @return A new $coll which contains the first occurrence of every element of this $coll.
*/
  def distinct: Repr = {
    val b = newBuilder
    val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
    for (x <- this) {
      if (!seen(x)) {
        b += x
        seen += x
      }
    }
    b.result
  }
```

So it appears that if order preservation is important, use `distinct` otherwise, they're relatively just as expensive.

Comment: On a side note, the "distinct" implementation is not functional and uses mutable state and vals. Any reason why that's the case?

Comment: The computation it performs is by definition on a single thread. The mutable set it uses cannot be observed outside this method. The side-effects it accumulates are irrelevant to any of the advantages that the use of immutable structures and pure functional programming offer. Lastly, it is almost certainly significantly (in the true sense of the word, not as a synonym for "substantially") faster than it would be if written using an immutable accumulator set.